# Replace string value with javascript object

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, object, template-engine

I am currently making a small module for NodeJs. For which I need a small help.

I will tell it like this.
I have a variable with string. It contains a string html value. Now I need to replace `$(title)` something like this with my object `{ "title" : "my title" }`. This can be expanded to anything with user provide. This is current code.I think that I need RegEx for do this. Can you guys help me with this?

```js
var html = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document $(title)</title>
</head>
<body>

  <h1>Test file, $(text)</h1>

</body>
</html>`;

function replacer(html, replace) {
  // i need a regex to replace these data
  //return replacedData;
}

replacer(html, { "title" : "my title", "text" : "text is this" });
```

Comment: Since you are using node, use one of the many competent templating engines out there, such as ejs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a simple template function using regex,

```
var replacer = function(tpl, data) {
  var re = /\$\(([^\)]+)?\)/g, match;
  while(match = re.exec(tpl)) {
    tpl = tpl.replace(match[0], data[match[1]])
    re.lastIndex = 0;
  }
  return tpl;
}
```

use like

```
var result = replacer(html, { "title" : "my title", "text" : "text is this" });
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b8cuqbkb/)

[detail here](http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/Javascript-template-engine-in-just-20-line)

**EDIT**

Actually as torazaburo mentioned in the comment, it can be refactored as

```
var replacer = function(tpl, data) {
    return tpl.replace(/\$\(([^\)]+)?\)/g, function($1, $2) { return data[$2]; });
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b8cuqbkb/1/)

hope this helps

Comment: Well, sure, but this won't work with things like `$(title.toUpperCase())`.

Comment: You could skip the loop and just say `return tpl.replace(/\$\(([^\)]+)?\)/g, function(_, match) { return data[match]; });`.

Comment: @torazaburo, OP did not asked for a complex replacer and most of the time the simple one is needed. And rightly so i have refactored the replace function

Comment: I just tried it in Chrome's console, it's not replacing anything in my string.

Answer (score 8):

This solution uses [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings) to do everything you want.

This solution has the advantage that, in contrast to the naive roll-your-own regexp-based template replacement strategy as proposed in another answer, it supports arbitrary calculations, as in

```
replacer("My name is ${name.toUpperCase()}", {name: "Bob"});
```

In this version of `replacer`, we use `new Function` to create a function which takes the object properties as parameters, and returns the template passed in evaluated as a template string. Then we invoke that function with the values of the object properties.

```
function replacer(template, obj) {
  var keys = Object.keys(obj);
  var func = Function(...keys, "return `" + template + "`;");

  return func(...keys.map(k => obj[k]));
}
```

We define the template using `${}` for substitutions (instead of `$()`), but escaping as `\${` to prevent evaluation. (We could also just specify it as a regular string literal, but would then lose multi-line capability).

```
var html = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document \${title}</title>  <!-- escape $ -->
</head>
<body>

  <h1>Test file, \${text}</h1>       <!-- escape $ -->

</body>
</html>`;
```

Now things work exactly as you want:

```
replacer(html, { "title" : "my title", "text" : "text is this" });
```

Simple example:

```
> replacer("My name is ${name}", {name: "Bob"})
< "My name is Bob"
```

Here's an example of calculated fields:

```
> replacer("My name is ${name.toUpperCase()}", {name: "Bob"})
< "My name is BOB"
```

or even

```
> replacer("My name is ${last ? lastName : firstName}", 
    {lastName: "Jones", firstName: "Bob", last: true})
< "My name is Jones"
```

Comment: Any way to get that replacer to work when the template string references a key that does not exist in "obj"?

Comment: "eval" can be dangerous

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using ES6 template string you can use a feature called ['tagged template strings'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings). Using tagged template strings you are allowed to modify the output of a template string. You create tagged template string by putting a 'tag' in front of the template string, the 'tag' is a reference to a method that will receive the string parts in a list as the first argument and the interpolation values as remaining arguments. The MDN page on template strings already provides an example template string 'tag' that we can use:

```
function template(strings, ...keys) {
  return (function(...values) {
    var dict = values[values.length - 1] || {};
    var result = [strings[0]];
    keys.forEach(function(key, i) {
      var value = Number.isInteger(key) ? values[key] : dict[key];
      result.push(value, strings[i + 1]);
    });
    return result.join('');
 });
}
```

You use the 'tag' by calling:

```
var tagged = template`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document ${'title'}</title>
</head>
<body>

  <h1>Test file, ${'text'}</h1>

</body>
</html>`;
```

Notice that interpolation of variables uses the syntax `${'key'}` instead of `$(key)`. You can now call the produced function to get the desired result:

```
tagged({ "title" : "my title", "text" : "text is this" });
```

Run the code example on [es6console](http://es6console.com/ija4z8il/)

Comment: i use NodeJs Streams to read the html file. can i use it with this?

Comment: NodeJS 5.0 and 4.0 supports template strings (when you start node with --harmony) , but you can not transform input streams to template strings. They have to be constructed by the ` ticks

Comment: I don't think you need the `--harmony` flag for template strings.

Answer (score 1):

I used prototype. it looks cleaner.

```
String.prototype.replaceByObject = function(obj) {
    return this.replace(RegExp(Object.keys(obj).join('|'), 'g'), function(val) {
        return obj[val];
    });
}
```

use it like this

```
html.replaceByObject({
    "title" : "my title",
    "text" : "text is this"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var binddingData=function(id,data){
    var me=this,
        arr=[];
    arr=getControlBindding(id);
    arr.forEach(function(node){
        var content=getBinddingContent(node.getAttribute('DataTemp'),data);
        binddingToHtml(node,content);
    })

}
var getControlBindding=function(id){
    var me=this;
    return document.querySelectorAll('[DataTemp]');
}


var getBinddingContent=function(temp,data){
    var me=this,
        res='',
        hasNull=false;
    if(temp==null||typeof temp=='undefined'){
            return res;
        }
    res= temp.replace(/\$\{([^\}]+)?\}/g, function($1, $2) { 
        if(data[$2]==null||typeof data[$2]=='undefined'){
            hasNull=true;
        }
        return data[$2]; 
    });
    return hasNull?'':res;

}

var binddingToHtml=function(node,content){
    var me=this;
    if(node.getAttribute('IsDateTime')){
        node.innerText='';//if u want change it to datetime string
        return;
    }
    if(node.getAttribute('AddBr') && content==''){
        node.innerText='';
        var brTag=document.createElement('br');
        node.appendChild(brTag);
        return;
    }
   node.innerText=content;
}
```

You use the 'tag' by calling:

```
<div DataTemp="${d1}"></div> 
    <div DataTemp="${d2}"></div>
    <div DataTemp="${d3}"></div> 
    <div DataTemp="${d3}+ +${d1}"></div> 
    <div DataTemp="${d3}/${d1}"></div>     
    <div DataTemp="${d4}\${d1}"></div>     
    <div DataTemp="(${d5}\${d1})"></div> 
    <div DataTemp="(${d3}\${d1})"></div>
```

with data `var data={d1:'t1',d2:'t2',d3:'t3'}`

Comment: Welcome to SO. To make your answer helpful, please give a description at first and then post your code for solving the problem.